# How to create an array of names in custom class

Tags: c#, .net, class

So I'm creating a new tool in C# and I've created a class called 'Customer' and each 'Customer' has sub-group of employees which is an array of names. How do I set this property in my class for 'Customer'? What I have below for 'Employees' is not correct. I just left it there as a placeholder.
Thank you

```
public class Customer
{
    public String Number { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Street { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string[] Employees = { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `List` instead? `List<string>`

Comment: How would i write that properly in my code?

Comment: What's wrong with `public string[] Employees { get; set; }`?

Comment: You just need to remove the '=' sign

Comment: Thanks Rufus, I forgot to remove the equal sign, I wasn't sure if the general method i was after was correct. thanks

Comment: @JokerMartini. Although it was small typo but now you have option to improve it further. Checkout answer using `List<string>` instead of `string array`.

Comment: I'm using List instead. I'm always for learning and improving. Thanks Hassan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `List` instead of an array as it is easier to manipulate:

```
public class Customer
{
    public String Number { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Street { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Zipcode { get; set; }
    public List<string> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And then when you instantiate it, you could add new employers as such:

```
Customer customer = new Cusomter();
customer.Number = "num1";
customer.Name = "ABC";
//...

List<string> lstEmp = new List<string>();
lstEmp.Add("NewEmployee1");
lstEmp.Add("NewEmployee2");

customer.Employees = lstEmp;
```

And read it like this:

```
foreach (string name in customer.Employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: `List<string>` is better choice :)

Comment: I'm going to use this List method as it's the better way to go based on everything you guys are saying . Thanks again guys

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this declaration:

```
public string[] Employees { get; set; }
```